# How to change the location of the symbols/text within a legend box?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, subplot, legend-properties

I have a subplot with a single legend entry. I am placing the legend at the bottom of the figure and using `mode='expand'`; however, the single legend entry is placed to the very left of the legend box. To my understanding, changing kwargs such as `bbox_to_anchor` changes the legend box parameters but not the parameters of the symbols/text within. Below is an example to reproduce my issue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
y = np.exp(x)
z = x **2

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
axes[0].plot(x, y, color='r', label='exponential')
axes[1].plot(x, z, color='b')
# handles, labels = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.125)
fig.legend(mode='expand', loc='lower center')
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

This code produces [image: this image]. How can I change the position of the symbol and text such that they are centered in the legend box?

PS: I am aware that exponential is a bad label for this subplot since it only describes the first subfigure. But, this is just for examples-sake so that I can apply it to my actual use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legend entries are placed using a `HPacker` object. This does not allow to be centered. The behaviour is rather that those HPackers are "justified" (similar to the "justify" option in common word processing software).

A workaround would be to create three (or any odd number of) legend entries, such that the desired entry is in the middle. This would be accomplished via the `ncol` argument and the use of "dummy" entries (which might be transparent and have no associated label).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
y = np.exp(x)
z = x **2

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.125)

l1, = axes[0].plot(x, y, color='r', label='exponential')
axes[1].plot(x, z, color='b')


dummy = plt.Line2D([],[], alpha=0)
fig.legend(handles=[dummy, l1, dummy],
           mode='expand', loc='lower center', ncol=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So close I was with ncol=3 idea :) Just missed the Line2D part